# Git submodule - track a subfolder of a foreign Git repo

Tags: git-submodules, git-subtree, git-subrepo

Say we are using git submodule:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/user/repo
```

I am wondering if there is a way to tracker a specific folder, something like this:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/user/repo -- xxx
```

is something like this possible?

For example, say we we have this in our .gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "config"]
    path = config
    url = https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

so what I am looking for is the config folder in my local project to reflect the xxx folder in the other/remote repo.

Comment: Git works on the repo and there is no way to track a folder (atleast that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

> is something like this possible?

Not that I know of.

One way would be to:

- add the submodule in one folder

  ```
  git submodule add https://url/repo afolder
  ```
- record a symlink to the right submodule subfolder

  ```
  ln -s afolder/xxx xxx
  git add xxx
  ```